# Green emblem with a number on the Files icon that doesn't want to go away

Tags: files, dock, emblem

There is a green emblem with a number on the Files icon in the Dock that doesn't want to go away.

[image: Files with emblem]

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

It indicates a previous completed file operation. To remove it, click on the Time and Date on top(GNOME) to view all notification. You might see the file operation successful message. Click on the x mark and clear the notification to clear the green indicator.